# jq is hanging when trying to extract data from json

Tags: jq

My Json file has following structure

```
{
"group0": [
    {
        "id": 9,
        "href": "href1",
        "name": "Americas",
        "group1": [
            {
                "id": 8,
                "href": "href2",
                "name": "Anguilla (UK)",
                "type": "country",
                "code": "ai",
                "group2": {
                    "field1": 9,
                    "field2": 1,
                    "field3": 1
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "href": "href3",
                "name": "Antigua and Barbuda",
                "type": "country",
                "code": "ag",
                "group2": {
                    "field1": 9,
                    "field2": 1,
                    "field3": 2
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 10,
                "href": "href4",
                "name": "Argentina",
                "type": "country",
                "code": "ar",
                "group2": {
                    "field1": 8,
                    "field2": 1,
                    "field3": 2
                },
                "group3": [
                    {
                        "id": 599,
                        "href": "",
                        "name": "Rosario and Santa Fe (both Santa Fe province)",
                        "field3": 3
                    }
                ]
            }

        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "href": "href5",
        "name": "Asia & the Pacific",
        "group1": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "href": "href6",
                "name": "Afghanistan",
                "type": "country",
                "code": "af",
                "group2": {
                    "field1": 10,
                    "field2": 3,
                    "field3": 5
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 14,
                "href": "href7",
                "name": "Australia",
                "type": "country",
                "code": "au",
                "group2": {
                    "field1": 7,
                    "field2": 1,
                    "field3": 2
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 19,
                "href": "href8",
                "name": "Bangladesh",
                "type": "country",
                "code": "bd",
                "group2": {
                    "field1": 9,
                    "field2": 2,
                    "field3": 3
                },
                "group3": [
                    {
                        "id": 216,
                        "href": "",
                        "name": "Chittagong Hill Tracts; Dhaka",
                        "field3": 4
                    }
                ]
            }

        ]
    }  
]
```

}

i want to extract the fileds group1.field0, group1.name,group2.field1, group1.field3

the command i am running is below

```
jq '.group0[].group1[]|"\(.name)|\(.field0)|\(.group2.field1)|\(.group2.field3)"' sample.json
```

when i run the above command in Solaris it just hangs and does nothing. when i run the below command i am getting data

```
jq '.group0[].group1[]|"\(.name)|\(.field0)"' sample.json
```

can someone please help me what am i doing wrong. the first command is working on jqplay.org which uses jq version 1.5 and jq version on our server is 1.4. i don't know whether lower version may be the issue(latest version for Solaris is 1.4 only).

Comment: Are you **really** running that command by hand, or is it invoked via a script? Did you test with the exact command copied-and-pasted? If your script weren't passing in the filename, that's the quickest/easiest way to reach the bug in question. If you run the shell script that's invoking `jq` with `sh -x yourscript` (or `bash -x yourscript`, or otherwise as-appropriate), could you give us the log line it emits before `jq` starts?

Comment: A [mcve] that works for people not on Solaris would make this far more answerable.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, i am running that command by hand.

Comment: Note that "latest version for Solaris is 1.4 only" is only true if you aren't compiling your own executable; the 1.5 source should compile there just fine.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, thanks for the suggestion, will talk to our admins about compiling it.

Comment: Do you really need help from an admin? You can compile software in your home directory with no extra permissions needed unless your admin staff went out of their way to make it so you can't. `./configure --prefix=$HOME/local && make && make install` in an unpacked source tree will create `~/local/bin/jq`; since it's in your home directory, you don't need `sudo` or other privilege escalation.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, can you please let me know which one to download and compile ?

Comment: If you want the 1.5 release's source, that would be https://github.com/stedolan/jq/archive/jq-1.5.tar.gz

Comment: i ran the command and am getting this error at the end --prefix=/usr/local: No such file or directory

Comment: To be clear, I'm telling you to use a `--prefix` that points to a place inside your home directory. You **must not** use `/usr` or `/usr/local`, because only admins can write to those locations.

Comment: Also, note that `--prefix=...whatever...` is an argument to the `configure` command. When I told you to run `./configure --prefix=$HOME/local`, that's all one command.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, thanks for the reply, even i created a folder with name 'local' and still getting the same error

Comment: `--prefix=/usr/local: No such file or directory` says you're trying to run `--prefix=` as a command. It's  not a command. It's an argument to `configure`. You need to invoke it that way. I don't know how I can rephrase to make this clearer.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, so here is the back ground, i download the source and extracted it to the folder named "jq-jq-1.5" in my home directory then ran the following commands inline `cd jq-jq-1.5` and then ran the command inline  `./configure --disable-maintainer-mode && --prefix=$HOME && make && make install`

Comment: The `&&` before the `--prefix` makes that into a separate shell command, and should not be there. It should just be `./configure --disable-maintainer-mode --prefix="$HOME/local" && make && make install`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, now i am getting the error "make: Fatal error in reader: Makefile, line 1586: Badly formed macro assignment"

Comment: Interesting -- sounds like the version of `make` you're using doesn't like something in the configure scripts. Unless you have GNU `make` available (try under the name `gmake`?), this might be a place where you need to file a ticket with the project; upstream autoconf tries to be quite widely compatible, so hopefully what we have is a local customization.

Comment: ...another thing you could try is rerunning `make distclean` and then `autoreconf -i`, assuming you have a new enough toolchain to provide the latter.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, thank you will try that out.

Comment: seems there is some bug in jq 1.4 for Solaris. it is working in every other OS. we were not able to compile jq 1.5 for Solaris as there are some errors

Comment: How does `jq -r '.group0[].group1[] | [.name, .field0, .group2.field1, .group2.field3] | @csv'` behave? Is it only the string-concatenation codepath where you have issues?

Comment: ...so, at the risk of a fugly hack, you might use `.group0[].group1[]|[.name, .field0, .group2.field1, .group2.field3] | @tsv | gsub("\t"; "|")` if there's no chance of tabs in the data.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, the issue is getting the values .group2.field1, .group2.field3. i was able to get the values for .name and .field0. string concatenation path is not an issue. here is the output of truss (equivalent of strace)

Comment: I have no interest in the syscall-level logs, unless you have a specific, interesting/worthwhile OS-level error elucidated by them

Comment: Frankly, what it looks like to me is that you have a parser bug -- which, if we're depending on OS-provided libraries, could very easily be a place where something breaks only in a specific context, such as when `"\(foo.bar)"` syntax is used. Which is why I'm asking about trying to make your query less interesting, syntactically -- so we're not exercising corner cases in the version of yacc that compiled it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ok, yeah i tried all the different ways for the query and it is hanging when i try to extract the group2 fields. i am even able to extract group3 fields.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] -- the shortest query, and the shortest data (thus, with the fewest nesting layers, etc), that generates your bug?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, the sample data i provide while opening the discussion is the shortest of data i can provide
below commands when i run it, it doesn't do anything(kind of in hanging state)
`jq -r '.' file.json`
`jq -r '.group0[].group1[]|.group2.field1' file.json`
below commands return output 
`jq -r '.group0[].group1[]|"\(.name)|\(.field0)"' file.json`

Comment: Nonsense. To pick the very first thing I can see -- nothing in your code uses the `href`s, for example, so your data could be shorter to exclude them. Or the `id`s, or the `name`s. And if the problem still takes place with fewer nesting levels, you can take away the outer ones (f/e, taking `group0` out of the data *and* the query, if the issue can be reproduced without it).

Comment: See "Tricks for Trimming" in http://sscce.org/.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, by removing the unwanted fields, you mean delete everything that is not needed ? is there a command to remove them or it is manually deleting them?

Comment: I'm referring to manually editing both your code and your data to generate the shortest, simplest possible working test case.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, small update here, our admin team installed jq on Solaris X86 server and the commands ran fine but our app servers are Solaris Spark ones. they are going to re-install jq and test it again

Answer (score 0):

I have verified that the problem does NOT arise when using jq 1.4, jq 1.5, or the "development" version (master), on MacOS.

Nevertheless, I think it would be worthwhile to upgrade to jq 1.5 or later.

The following might well work: replace 
`(.group2.field1)` by `(.group2|.field1)` and similarly for `(.group2.field2)`

Comment: i tried replacing as per your suggestion but it didn't work. also i tried commands on Windows version of jq 1.5 and it is working. So may be we need to have jq 1.5 to make this work.